# Where is the sqlite database that holds the global settings stored on nougat?

Tags: android, sqlite

On earlier versions it was settings.db in `data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases`

But this seems only to be the case for earlier version, in nougat it has moved.

Answer (score 6):

According to this [commit](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/commit/683914bfb13908bf380a25258cd45bcf43f13dc9#diff-424ba9f390d949f3b751919766180a22) it has been moved to XML files located in /data/system/users/userid/settings_[system|global|secure].xml"

Answer (score 0):

I see the database here: `/data/user/0/com.android.providers.settings/databases`

Edit: After doing some quick research on the topic, I found the following:

- `/data/data` was the storage location for earlier versions of Android (pre-4.2 I think) that only supported single users.
- Android 4.2 introduced the concept of segmenting data by user so the user data can now be found in `/data/user/0`, `/data/user/1`,`/data/user/2`, ...
- For backwards-compatibility, `/data/user/0`, appears to be a symlink to `/data/data` (or vice-versa)

So you can look for your database in the above mentioned directories: `/data/user/0`, `/data/user/1`,`/data/user/2`

Comment: it's not there for me (S8 Android 7)